# FTP error 530 Permission denied?

Tags: ftp

I get an *Error 530 Permission Denied* when I try to access an FTP server on my LAN, even though user&pass are correct. I get 530 when I FTP to it from the same machine, and from another machine on the LAN. How can I solve this error? (Update added below.)

What I want:

- run an FTP server on a home computer so I can put backups on it from other machines (from same home LAN and also from outside)

What I have:

- Windows Vista on a home computer
- DSL connection and [dynamic DNS service](http://www.no-ip.com/services/managed_dns/free_dynamic_dns.html)
- either one of [FileZilla Server](http://wiki.filezilla-project.org/FileZilla_FTP_Server) or [smallftpd](http://smallftpd.sourceforge.net/),

  - each configured with a user and a public directory,
  - and the service started,
  - and unblocked in the Vista firewall.

Update:
Login succeeds when connecting using local IP address, but not when using the dynamic IP.
That would indicate an issue with the router or other kind of DNS-related stuff, but if that were the case then the FTP server wouldn't even respond, would it? It *does* respond but doesn't accept the login credentials -- I'm stumped!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So you have an FTP running on a Vista machine and you have dynamic DNS setup on your router?  You didn't mention if you have port 21 forwarded to the FTP machine.

Also, I have had problems in the past with not being able to connect to a Filezilla FTP, however when I logged in as a local administrator on the FTP machine, other computers could then connect to the FTP.

Comment: Ha! The missing puzzle piece was to have my DSL router forward port 21 to the pc. Now it works.  
Since you mention being logged in as admin -- the machine is always on and a user with admin rights is always logged in (hey, it's Windows...).